# How do I invoke this native method from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I want to invoke one/many functions of a native library but I am unsure on the type mappings.  The function in particular I am currently trying is as follows, here is the small console app which I am spiking in:

```
extern char *tgetstr (const char *name, char **area);
```

And here is my attempt at mapping this to use in a .NET console.  **I get an error saying, trying to read or write protected memory.**

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("termcap.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr tgetstr(IntPtr name, IntPtr area);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr ptr1 = new IntPtr();
        IntPtr a = tgetstr(Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi("cl"), ptr1);
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(a));
    }
}
```

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your `IntPtr` by `ref`, so the function can overwrite it.  Then you also need to free the string after you've copied it, hopefully the DLL provides a matching deallocation function.  `StringToCoTaskMemAnsi` isn't helping you any either, it's just leaking memory.

The correct p/invoke declaration is probably

```
[DllImport("termcap.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr tgetstr(string name, ref IntPtr area);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with unmanaged code since 3 years but I think you can do it by marking the method parameters with MarshalAs attribute. Check this article,

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pin your ptr1.

`GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(ptr1, GCHandleType.Pinned);`

Comment: That only affects the address of `ptr1` not the value (the address stored inside), so won't make any difference.  Plus the p/invoke layer would do that automatically.